# How can I use rspec shared_examples to test my controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm upgrading a site to use devise and I have the following specs to test `SitesController`:

```
describe SitesController do
  let(:user)  { FactoryGirl.create(:user)  }
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin) }

  shared_examples "disallow get index" do
    get :index
    response.should_not be_success
  end

  context "with user signed in" do
    before(:each) { sign_in user }

    it "disallowes / with GET" do
      get :index
      response.should_not be_success
    end

    it_behaves_like "disallow get index"
  end

  context "with admin signed in" do
    before(:each) { sign_in admin }

    it "allowes / with GET" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add a context where no user is signed in and use the shared example `disallow get index` to specify that you can't do that if you're not signed in. BUT, when I add `it_behaves_like "disallow get index"` I get this undefined method error:

```
sites_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `get' for #<Class:0x00000101746718> (NoMethodError)
```

So, why does this work when I explicitly call `get :index` but not in a shared example group?

Comment: Does `controller.get` work?

Comment: No. That doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a very simple fix. I was using `shared_examples` to replace an `it` block like this:

```
shared_examples "disallow get index" do
  get :index
  response.should_not be_success
end
```

When `shared_examples` is really a "replacement" for a `context` block. So, you need to have `it` blocks inside your `shared_examples`:

```
shared_examples "disallow get index" do
  it "fails on index" do
    get :index
    response.should_not be_success
  end
end
```